# AIR vs Autohotkey vs C# for quick windows form + output

Tags: c#, winforms, air

I've been using Autohotkey to create quickie GUI apps that take data, apply styles and formatting, and output to clipboard or to a flat file. These are "mini applications" for users who need to work in an HTML environment but don't know anything about tags.

I've thought about going beyond Autohotkey and I'm looking at both Windows Forms (C#) and Adobe AIR.

As someone with some winforms and AHK experience, is Air something I could pick up? I might have a couple of Mac or Linux users, but that's not my sole criteria.

Comment: Well... AIR is cross-platform. neither AHK nor C# isn't cross-platform (C# + Mono may works...). Also check AutoIt, it's similar to AHK and I liked it better. For another option, I suggest you to check Python + a simple GUI toolkit (TkInter is good enough for you IMO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Adobe AIR, but I've used C# + Winforms to write many quick (windows) GUI apps to great effect. Working with text files in .NET is a breeze, and Winforms has a convenient [ClipBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) class. As far as linux and mac go, both have mono support. Granted, the apps probably won't run as well as they would on windows, but the mono guys are doing a fantastic job so you might want to at least try it out.